# Randomising 2 PHP Arrays - working now

Tags: php, arrays

Works Now.

I need my page to randomise questions using those 2 arrays but 'question' and 'answer' need to match and I dont know how to do that.

```
<?php
  $question=[
    "Favourite game?","Favourite Drink?","Favourite Fast Food?","Favourite TV show?","Favourite chocolate?"
  ];
  $answer=[
  ["Super Mario","Battlefield", "Counter Strike", "Fifa"],
  ["Coke","Tea","coffee","Water"],
  ["Pizza","Fish and Chips","Burger","Hot Dog"],
  ["The Walking Dead","Prison Break","Breaking Bad","Game of Thrones"],
  ["Mars","Snickers","Diary Milk","Galaxy"]];
  ?>
<form action="results.php" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="timer" id="timer"/>
  <p>You have 120 seconds (2 minutes) to answer <?php print $numofquestions ?> question(s)</p>
  <br>
  <?php
    for($i = 0; $i<$numofquestions; $i++) 
    {
        print "<p>".$question[$i]."</p><select name='answer[]'>";

        for($j = 0; $j<count($answer[$i]); $j++)
        {
            print "<option value = '".($j + 1)."'>".$answer[$i][$j]."   </option>";
        }
    print "</select>";
    }
    ?>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Answers" onclick="sendto()">
</form>
```

---

above is solved but now there is a second problem. When using this php code to print selected number of questions from previous page, it prints 1 extra question than it should.----Works Now!

this code allows me to get the number of questions in questions.php

```html
?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['firstname'] = $_GET['firstname'];
  $fname = $_SESSION['firstname'];
  $_SESSION['numofquestions'] = $_GET['numofquestions'];
  $numofquestions = $_SESSION['numofquestions'];
  ?>
```

And this is the php in questions.php

```
<?php
  $question=[
    "Favourite game?","Favourite Drink?","Favourite Fast Food?","Favourite TV show?","Favourite chocolate?"
  ];
  $answer=[
  ["Super Mario","Battlefield", "Counter Strike", "Fifa"],
  ["Coke","Tea","coffee","Water"],
  ["Pizza","Fish and Chips","Burger","Hot Dog"],
  ["The Walking Dead","Prison Break","Breaking Bad","Game of Thrones"],
  ["Mars","Snickers","Diary Milk","Galaxy"]];
  ?>
<form action="results.php" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="timer" id="timer"/>
  <p>You have 120 seconds (2 minutes) to answer <?php print $numofquestions ?> question(s)</p>
  <br>
  <?php
    $keys = array_keys($question);
    shuffle($keys);
    $cnt = $numofquestions;
    foreach($keys as $i)        
    {
    print "<p>".$question[$i]."</p><select name='answer[]'>";

    for($j = 0; $j<count($answer[$i]); $j++)
    {
    print "<option value = '".($j + 1)."'>".$answer[$i][$j]."</option>";
    }
    print "</select>";
    if(!$cnt--) break;
    }
    ?>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Answers" onclick="sendto()">
</form>
```

Comment: Where is the file `questions.php`?, please add the code of that file, or at least the part of it that handles the number of questions.

Comment: made changes, above each code there is a file name

Comment: And the code that contains: `<?php session_start(); ...?>` is part of `questions.php` file?

Comment: yes its part of questions.php

Comment: I just answered a possible solution, check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

index.php:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Guessing Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mainstyle.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> Guessing Game </h1>
    <br>
    <p>In this guessing game, I will be able to guess your age.</p>
    <form action="questions.php" method="post">
      <p>Please enter your name:</p>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" />
      <p>How many questions would you like to answer?[1-5]</p>
      <select name="numofquestions" />
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
      </select>
      <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Start"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

questions.php

```
   <?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['numofquestions'] = isset($_POST['numofquestions']) ? intval($_POST['numofquestions']) : 5;
    $_SESSION['name'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstname']);

     $questions  = [
        "Favourite game?","Favourite Drink?","Favourite Fast Food?","Favourite TV show?","Favourite chocolate?"
      ];

     $_SESSION['questions'] = $questions;

     $questions = array_slice($questions, 0, $_SESSION['numofquestions']); 


      $answers =[
        ["Super Mario","Battlefield", "Counter Strike", "Fifa"],
        ["Coke","Tea","coffee","Water"],
        ["Pizza","Fish and Chips","Burger","Hot Dog"],
        ["The Walking Dead","Prison Break","Breaking Bad","Game of Thrones"],
        ["Mars","Snickers","Diary Milk","Galaxy"]
      ];
      ?>
    <form action="results.php" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="timer" id="timer"/>
          <p>You have 120 seconds (2 minutes) to answer <?php echo count($questions) ?> question(s)</p>
          <br>
<?php
  $questionKeys = array_keys($questions);
  shuffle($questionKeys);

  foreach($questionKeys as $questionID){

    echo $questions[$questionID];
    echo '<select name="answer'.$questionID.'">';

    foreach($answers[$questionID] as $answer){
            echo '<option value="' . $answer . '">'.$answer.'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select><br>';

  }
           ?>
             <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Answers" >
</form>
```

results.php

```
<?php
session_start();

echo '<h1>Results for: ' .  $_SESSION['name'] . '</h1>';
$counter = intval($_SESSION['numofquestions']) -1;
 while($counter >= 0){
    echo $_SESSION['questions'][$counter] . ' has value ' . $_POST['answer' . $counter] . '<br>';
    $counter--;
 }
```

Comment: this is not randomizing questions even using 
$keys = array_keys($question);
shuffle($keys);

   foreach($keys as $i)
from splash58

Comment: @Wlod do you want to randomize the question order? or the dropdown options? please clarify your question.

Comment: question order please

Comment: @Wlod i edited the sourcecode. It should work now ;)

Comment: Thanks solved the problem but got a different problem now where I talked about with @splash58

Comment: @Wlod so when someone submits the form you want to display the amount of items in the question array? or the order of the question array or the answers? please edit your question to include a detailed version of "the desired result"

Comment: @Wlod i added some examples.

Comment: thanks its working now - just had to put -1 in the session and it worked thanks!

Comment: @Wlod no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Make array of keys and randomize it. Change your `for($i = 0; $i<$numofquestions; $i++)` with lines below

```
$keys = array_keys($question);
shuffle($keys);

   foreach($keys as $i)
```

Comment: still gives me a fixed order of questions

Comment: have you change your for loop with these 3 lines?

Comment: its working but got a next problem now, i need $numofquestions to get the number of questions from previous page do I just do this foreach($keys as $i < $numofquestions) ??

Comment: init counter before foreach `$cnt = $numofquestions;` and add at the end of the loop `if( ! $cnt--) break;`

Comment: gives me 1 extra question than it should

Comment: I am out a computer now. Will be available to answer in 3 hours

Answer (score 0):

meaning you need to match with the right answer right? If so:

you can relate questions and answers with multi-dimensional array and after use array_key_exists, something like that

```
<?php
$question = array(1 => "Favourite game?",
               2 => "Favourite Drink?",
               3 => "Favourite Fast Food?",
               4 => "Favourite TV show?",
               5 => "Favourite chocolate?");
$answer = array(
    1 => array('right_answer' => "Super Mario", "Battlefield", "Counter Strike", "Fifa"),
    2 => array("Coke","Tea",'right_answer' => "coffee","Water"),
    3 => array("Pizza","Fish and Chips",'right_answer' => "Burger","Hot Dog"),
    4 => array("The Walking Dead",'right_answer' => "Prison Break","Breaking Bad","Game of Thrones"),
    5 => array("Mars",'right_answer' => "Snickers","Diary Milk","Galaxy")
```

);

this is just a ideia, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, tweak a little bit, I limited the $keys array to contain only the number of questions specified by the user. there's, at least two equivalent ways, to accomplish the same behavior.

```
<?php
//This is less error prone
    $numofquestions = $_GET['numofquestions'];
    for($i = 0; $i < $numofquestions; $i++) {
        $question_trimmed[$i] = $question[$i]; 
    }
    $keys = array_keys($question_trimmed);          
    shuffle($keys);
```

And

```
<?php
//this is shorter
    $numofquestions = $_GET['numofquestions'];
    $keys = range(0, $numofquestions - 1);
    shuffle($keys);
```

Try them, and tell us if your problem is solved

**Note:** you don't need the `$cnt` variable or the last conditional statement `if(!$cnt--) break;`.